# How to stack divs from the bottom of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have such a code:

```
*{
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container{
width: 206px;
}

#content{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
height: 100px;
background-color: brown;
color: white;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.tile{
float: left;
margin: 3px;
padding: 3px;
background-color: white;
color: black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

<div id="container">
<div id="content">
<div class="tile">1</div>
<div class="tile">2</div>
<div class="tile">3</div>
<div class="tile">4</div>
<div class="tile">5</div>
<div class="tile">6</div>
<div class="tile">7</div>
<div class="tile">8</div>
<div class="tile">9</div>
<div class="tile">10</div>
<div class="tile">11</div>
<div class="tile">12</div>
<div class="tile">13</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have used vertical-align: bottom but it's not working 100% as I would like to. It looks like this: https://ibb.co/cLD6GQ and I expect something like this: https://ibb.co/eJ8dVk 
Can you give me some advice?

Comment: That's not what vertical-align does.

Comment: vertical-align is working as expected: all content is on the bottom. If you want tiles to move from bottom to top, you will have to use any number of different methods to order them, a flex box model using some reverse wrap may work, ala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22830809/floating-divs-from-bottom-to-top-using-css

Comment: Use flexbox. I was about to post answer but it was marked duplicate just before I submitted, here is jsfilddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3den87yo/2/